# Why does Echad mi Yodeia switch languages in middle?

Tags: hebrew, passover-seder-hagada, language, aramaic

Why does echad mi yodeia switch from hebrew (eg. אֶחָד מִי יוֹדֵעַ? אֶחָד אֲנִי יוֹדֵעַ: אֶחָד אֱלֹהֵינוּ שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם וּבָאָרֶץ.) to arameic (eg. שִׁבְעָה יְמֵי שַׁבָּתָא), back to hebrew (eg. תִּשְׁעָה יַרְחֵי לֵדָה, שְׁמוֹנָה יְמֵי מִילָה), and then to arameic again (שְׁלשָׁה עָשָׂר מִדַּיָּא, שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר שִׁבְטַיָּא, אַחַד עָשָׂר כּוֹכְבַיָּא, עֲשָׂרָה דִבְּרַיָא)?

Comment: so 5 and up rhyme?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70693/3 Perhaps those two stand out in content as well as for for the same reason.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53689 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36837. Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37639